# Запрос INSERT в PostgreSQL (with Postgis) в Python'е

Tags: python, postgresql, insert

Есть таблица **concentration** в PostgreSQL:

```
BEGIN;
    CREATE TABLE concentration
    (
        gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
        mass double precision,
        area double precision,
        "data" date,
        "time" time without time zone
    );
END;
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('','concentration','the_geom','4326','POLYGON',2);
```

Необходимо сделать запрос **INSERT** в таблицу, в Python скрипте такой:

```
INSERT INTO concentration ("mass","area","data","time",the_geom) VALUES ('402.05','2654.36','2015-07-06','14:17',GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POLYGON((164 53, 165 53, 165 54, 164 54, 164 53))'));
```

Делаю так:

```
import psycopg2
 ...
 SQL = "INSERT INTO concentration (\"mass\",\"area\",\"data\",\"time\",the_geom) VALUES (%s);"
 data = "'402.05','2654.36','2015-07-06','14:17',GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POLYGON((164 53, 165 53, 165 54, 164 54, 164 53))')"

cursor.execute(SQL, data)
```

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Ругается на то, что используются кавычки  `"` и `'` вместе. Как победить?

Comment: А вы уверены, что в питоне так можно ? В куче других языков работа с базой идет привязыванием отдельных параметров и sql выглядит примерно `insert .... values(?,?,?,?...)` и последующий вызов `execute(parm1, parm2, parm3)`. причем sql функции типа GeomFromEWKT пишутся в теле запроса и если у них более 1 параметра так же принимают несколько подставляемых переменных при execute

Comment: Да, вы правы так делать НЕЛЬЗЯ. Модуль `Psycopg2`, сам правильно подставит переменные в SQL-запрос по типу. В нем многие стандартные типы Python уже адаптированы к правильному представлению SQL [ссылка](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Сам отвечаю. При передачи параметров в SQL-запросе этому модулю необходимо передавать типы переменных без всяких там кавычек [ссылка](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). В итоге для моего случая в скрипте всё будет выглядеть так:

```
import psycopg2
...
SQL = "INSERT INTO concentration (mass, area, data, time, the_geom) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, GeomFromEWKT(%s));"
data = (float(402.05), float(2654.36), datetime.date(2015, 07, 06), datetime.time(14,17), 'SRID=4326;POLYGON((164 53, 165 53, 165 54, 164 54, 164 53))')  
cursor.execute(SQL, data)
conn.commit()# это обязательно, иначе запрос не пойдет в таблицу
```

Comment: `type(402.05)` уже `float` -- не нужно `float()` вокруг добавлять.

Comment: @jfs Да вы знаете, я тоже так думал, но если делать без float() - ошибка:  `ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'numpy.float32'`

Comment: Это не имеет отношения к моему комментарию. В коде в Вашем ответе не нужно `float` использовать.

Answer (score 0):

все верно.
в psycopg2 есть метод [cur.mogrify()](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html)

используется для генерации запросов.

причем строка которая записана в тексте вопроса:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO concentration (\"mass\",\"area\",\"data\",\"time\",the_geom) VALUES (%s);"
```

Спокойно пропускает sql-инъекции.

[в документации:](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters)
Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

psycopg2 предоставляет возможность работать с любыми типами, даже с [composite type](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#composite-types-casting)

Если нет желания использовать ORM аля SQLAlchemy, psycopg2 предоставляет всю функциональность работы с postgresql. Скорость увеличивается, но что бы код читался нужно хорошо проштудировать документацию.